# How to pass "select" id into an ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**My ajax script**

```
function filter(){
  var input1 = $("#advanced-search1").val();
  $.ajax({
     dataType: 'html',
     url: "php/filter.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: input1,
     success: function(response){
           $('#result').html(response);
     }
  });
}
```

**The html form**

```
<form>
 <select id="advanced-search1" name="taskOption">
   <option value="apple">Apple</option>
   .
   .
   .
 </select>
 <input type="submit" onclick="filter()" value="Filter">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

My question is how to pass the "select" id into an ajax so that it can be processed in the other php file (filter.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `data` works is by using an object... What you are doing is wrong. Replace the `data` part with:

```
data: {"key": input1},
```

And in the server side you should be able to access it using:

```
$_POST["key"]
```

Comment: okay, and then which variable that i can carry or process in my other php file?

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty It's like whatever you need to replace instead of the `key`. You can also use `data` like this: `data: {"data": input1},`

Comment: alright i got it. but can you take a look at my php file over there. I can only see a flash of "successfully here". I think there's something wrong with the if(empty.....)

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty Haven't used `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'key', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);`

Comment: it's okay, but do you have any idea for the php side, on how i want to make sure that the second condition will not be executed depends on submit button not from the 'key'

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty `isset($_GET["key"]) && !empty($_GET["key"])` will be the one?

Comment: do i need to change everything in a _GET method?

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty Well, not exactly, but the above works... `:)` Why are you using `filter_input` here, when it is not required? It's only for sanitising the user input.

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty Yes, like I said, `isset($_GET["key"]) && !empty($_GET["key"])`. In this order, we need to check. `:)`

Comment: i can only view the output if it's in javascript alert

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty Sorry I went to bed after my last message... Did it get solved?